# Robot Framework - How to start with Appium Library?

Tags: appium, robotframework

I am trying automate Mobile application using AppiumLibrary in Robot Framework. Can anybody help me how to start with installing the Appium library in robot framework?

Comment: Please describe the problem you face in as much detail as you can with steps tried, observed results and expected results. At [so] we do expect a certain amount of effort to have been invested on your part before posting.

Comment: Hi@pranesh , I think you should follow this instruciton if you want to start with Appium  http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-tutorial/ . Anyway pls follow the rule of stackoverflow  .

Comment: As We know, Robot Framework is a generic test automation framework and  Appium Library is one of the external libraries of robot framework for mobile application testing. Currenty with the Robot Framework, i am able to automate the Web applications using Selenium Library. Similarly i wants to automate Mobile applications using Robot framework, for this i have to bring Appium Library in Robot framework. So here my doubt is, how we are going to make interaction between Robot Framework-Appium.  So how we can implement Appium Library with Robot Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be this can give you a head start, below are some key concepts to start with.

**What is Appium ?**

Appium works like a server, written in Nodejs and implements selenium webdriver . it allows the client (test cases written in any language, Robotframework in your case ) to fire the tests and the target application ( Apps) acts like a web page . Target application sends back the response to node js server which in turn send it back to client.

here is an excellent link which can help you to understand the basic concept of appium in more details

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/appium/

**Android SDK**

You need to install android SDK as it provides many set of tools to help in automation, one such tool is adb, it detect your mobile devices, assign device id to them, which will be referenced by your scripting language for further communication with appium.

**Client**

Third point is client i.e. Robot Framework.
You need to install appium library first

```
pip install robotframework-appiumlibrary
```

once you have library installed you can use it to send request to appium server.

here is a sample programe to open dialer in phone

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    This script starts apps on two phones
Library           AppiumLibrary
Library          Collections

*** Variables ***
${APPIUM_SERVER1}    http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub



*** Test cases ***
Test
    setup and open android phone1


*** Keywords ***
setup and open android phone1
    ${androiddriver1}=    Open Application    ${APPIUM_SERVER1}    platformName=android    platformVersion=7.0    deviceName=f1232233    automationName=uiautomator2
    ...    appPackage=com.samsung.android.contacts    newCommandTimeout=2500    appActivity=com.android.dialer.DialtactsActivity
    Set Suite Variable    ${androiddriver1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Lot of info.!
Yes, I installed appium library using command that you mentioned. But in RIDE, when i write,
(*** Settings ***
Library           AppiumLibrary)
It showing in Red colored text, that causing me the issue.!

Comment: Make sure following path is present in environment variable: "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages"

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in cmd after installing **robotframework-appiumlibrary**:

```
pip install --upgrade robotframework-appiumlibrary
```

It solved the same issue which I experienced.