# Where do we write Appium automation tests for apps whose source code is not freely available, like Whatsapp or Skype?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I need to learn how to automate Android apps such as Whatsapp, Skype etc. using Appium.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLZigIv82cA) to get started. They have taught how to set up Appium. That I did successfully. Then they taught how to run a first test on an application whose code is available. I used a basic app I wrote to do it. That is, within the src code of the project in Android Studio, I wrote a test class.

Now the problem is that the code of Android apps such as Whatsapp and Skype etc. is not available. So how do we write automation tests for those. More specifically, where do we write automation tests for those when the source code is not available?

Do we write a separate android application to write those test classes for such closed source Android apps? I have searched on the web, but they all started by starting to write a test class etc. But I am confused about where to write that test class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused

> 1) Appium just only provides API to interact with the devices and
>   perform different tasks
>
> 2) What exactly you need to test, you need to write down as
>   requirement .
>
> 3) requirements can be written as test cases by using any client. e.g.
>   Java,Python,RobotFramework
>
> 4) Test cases will interact with Appium to do the desired tasks for
>   you.

May be below URL can provide you a head start

[Robot Framework - How to start with Appiuum Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270837/robot-framework-how-to-start-with-appiuum-library/49277285#49277285)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate project to write test case for the app. You can write test case in any programming language such as java, python, javascript, ruby, php and c#. You can use any ide of your preference.

To test the app you don't need source code. All you need is to know their appPackage and appActivity. For automation testing you must have unique id or automation id in the app's element to interact with that element. Read ["How to find appPackage and appActivity"](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/) to get appPackage and appActivity.

To inspect mobile element you can use **appium desktop inspector**. Learn how to use [Appium Desktop Inspector](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop-inspector/).

**Required tools**

- [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/install)
- [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
- [Appium Server](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/#installing-appium)
- [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.6.2): Here is the [tutorial](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop/)
- IDE of your choice, i am using **intellij idea**

**Required jars**

- [Java-client 6.1.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/6.1.0)
- [selenium java 3.14.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.14.0)
- [Testng 6.14.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.14.3)

Here is the basic [tutorial](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-tutorial/) to get started with appium.