# Robot framework- Mobile automation test cases

Tags: robotframework

I have written test cases for desktop application in maven project using robot framework.Now, I need to run the same test cases for mobile (both android and iOS). I really don’t have any idea how to do that, Can anyone please help me or give me suggestion how Can I do that?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Appium?

Comment: No, but Can you please elaborate the steps how to install that in maven project and how can I run my current scripts with the Appium? FYI, those scripts are working for me on desktop browsers and I am using robot framework. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your code.

Comment: [Arguments]    ${Servicename}    ${newslettersignup}    ${Close}
    waitForPageLoaded
    Execute JavaScript    window.scrollTo(0,5000)
    Wait Until Element Is Visible   ${Servicename}    30      
    Click Element   ${Servicename}
    Click Element   ${NextbuttonStep1}  
    Input Text      ${Zipcode}    1234
    Click Element  ${NextbuttonStep2}   
    Click Element    ${newslettersignup}
    Click Element    ${Submitbutton}
    Wait until element is visible    ${Close}    30
    Click Element    ${Close}        I wanted to run the same test case in Mobile

Comment: This answer has everything you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270837/robot-framework-how-to-start-with-appiuum-library

Comment: Thank you so much! I will follow the steps and let you know if it goes well

Comment: I have installed python and pip command to add appium libraries to my system.But, I don't know how can i integrate the appium libraries in maven project. Can you please help me how can i do that? Many Thanks!